# Cannot find module './in-memory-data-service' in tour of heroes for Angular

Tags: angular, error-handling, angular-cli, webapi

[image]I'm getting error in tour of heroes in angular

**src/app/app.module.ts:12:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './in-memory-data.service'.**

```
import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';
```

How can i solve this issue .. due to this page is not working

Comment: See if this fixes the issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8920#issuecomment-223052268

Answer (score 0):

It worked for my by simply restarting the sever after installing the 'angular-in-memory-web-api'.